# Load 2 content into 2 div respectively jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to simplify this call?

```
$('.tag-widget a').click(event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    $('.products-grid').load(`${event.target.href} .products-grid`)
    $('.pagination-cubic').load(`${event.target.href} .pagination-cubic`)
})
```

Basically, when I click the link under the .tag-widget, I want the content from .pagination-cubic & .products-grid to load into its respective div.

The above codes work for me, but it's making 2 calls which affected the loading time. Can I combine them into 1?

I tried this below codes, but what happen is the .products-grid loads into both the .pagination-cubic & .products-grid.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.tag-widget a').click(event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        $('.products-grid, .pagination-cubic').load(`${event.target.href} .products-grid, .pagination-cubic`)
    })
});
```

P/s : Searching through the forum, I only found the way to insert 2 contents into 1 div only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs for `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) suggest that

> It is roughly equivalent to `$.get(url, data, success)` ...

So, you should be able to do something like this:

```
$.get(event.target.href, function(resp) {
  var resp = $(resp);

  $('.products-grid').html(resp.find('.products-grid').html());

  if (resp.find('.pagination-cubic').length > 0) {
    $('.pagination-cubic').html(resp.find('.pagination-cubic').html());
  } else {
    $('.pagination-cubic').html('');
  }
});
```

This will fetch the contents once and then set the HTML content of appropriate selectors.

Comment: understand, but what if some of the link page doesn't have the .pagination-cubic? It will show the .pagination-cubic from the previous result.

Comment: @NazrinNoorzan -- Not sure if I understood you correctly here. But, if the `$.get`'s response doesn't have `.pagination-cubic`, the previous content won't change. You may check if `.pagination-cubic` exists before setting the contents. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. The edited version works well. I'm always wondering how you guys know what to write/put. I mean I always stuck at what to write, but once someone wrote it, I can understand it.